# Push a local branch to origin using TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

Is there a way to do this in TortoiseGit?

git push -u origin (branch)

This is some extra meaningless text so that SO will accept the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the context menu on your working tree in Windows explorer and select TortoiseGit -> Push.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html